# How to do conditional formatting regarding dates in excel

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I have a table:

[image]

I want cells which top cell (B1, C1) is older than corresponding date value (column D) to be filled with red, as shown below:

[image]

Here C3 needn't be red because 15 Feb is in February.
How can I do this with conditional formatting?

Comment: Because 15-Feb is still in February. If top cell is in same month with "date" value, it needn't be red.

Comment: Please edit your question as per the suggestion of pnuts, so the "thread" is most useful for future readers.

Comment: Please add also the figure showing colored cells (it helped understanding the question). Thanks.

Comment: I will add the images later, right now I cannot upload images to SO.

Comment: I can't upload to web either.

Comment: It doesn't accept that link. I think png format is not allowed

Comment: all images are uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Conditional Formatting*, *Use a formula to determine...* and enter the formula

```
=DATE(YEAR($D2),MONTH($D2),1)>DATE(YEAR(B$1),MONTH(B$1),1)
```

(or the shorter `=EOMONTH(B$1,0)<EOMONTH($D2,0)` as suggested by pnuts),

[image]

and *Applies to*

```
=$B$2:$C$4
```

[image]

The formula gets rid of the day in each of the two cells to be compared, keeping only the months/years. It also uses suitable relative/absolute indexing for the matrix.
I have used both, each with different formatting, to test them at once.

Comment: @sancho.s thanks. how does that formula apply to the conditional formatted cells? conditional formatted cells are not arguments of that formula

Comment: @alwbtc - Fill the field *Applies to*.

Comment: Yes I did, but it works, but i cant understand the logic of conditional formatting. applied cells are not arguments of that formula

Comment: @alwbtc - Then, I guess you should tinker a little bit with Conditional formatting, on a range that is not of matrix type, but a simple linear range, and perhaps with a simpler formula (if all you need is understanding the range to which it applies). It may take you some 5 minutes to become familiar with it. All other features of Conditional formatting are very useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Conditional Formatting.
- Use a formula to determine.
- Enter the formula

```
=DATE(YEAR($D2),MONTH($D2),1)>DATE(YEAR(B$1),MONTH(B$1),1)
```